# Detail View is not displaying details of the post? Django

Tags: django

I have a list of aircraft displayed in browseaircraft.html. The user clicks on the title and is taken to the details page, however, it doesn't display the details of that particular post, rather all of the posts? There is no error message, but it's not working as expected

**Models**

```
class Aircraft(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
    range = models.IntegerField()
    cruise_speed = models.IntegerField()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('aircraftdetail', kwargs={'pk': self.id})
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^aircraft', 'aircraft.views.browseaircraft', name='browseaircraft'),
url(r'^aircraftdetail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'aircraft.views.aircraftdetail', name='aircraftdetail'),]
```

**Views**

```
def browseaircraft(request):
    all_aircraft = Aircraft.objects.all()
    variables = {'all_aircraft':all_aircraft}
    return render(request,'browseaircraft.html', variables)

def aircraftdetail(browseaircraft):
    model = Aircraft

def aircraft_detail_view(request,pk):
    try:
        aircraft_id=Aircraft.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except aircraft.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Book does not exist")
    return render(request,'aircraft_detail.html',
        context={'aircraft':aircraft_id,}
    )
```

**Browseaircraft.html**

```
  {% if all_aircraft%}
     {% for a in all_aircraft %}
       <img src="{{a.image.url}}"height="100" width="100">
       <a href="{{ a.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ a.title }}</a>
       {{ a.range }},
       {{ a.body }},
     {% endfor %}
```

**aircraft_detail.html**

```
{% block content %}
  {% for a in all_aircraft %}
    <h1>Title: {{ a.title }}</h1>
    {{ a.cost }}
    {{ a.range}}
    {{ a.cost }}
    {{ a.cruise_speed }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you ignored my perfectly correct answer when you asked this identical question a couple of days ago?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the issues pointed out by other posters, you have an issue with your urls.py. You do not terminate the pattern for your index view, so it matches everything that *starts with* "aircraft" - which includes "aircraftdetail". You should use `$` consistently:

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^aircraft/$', 'aircraft.views.browseaircraft', name='browseaircraft'),
url(r'^aircraftdetail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'aircraft.views. aircraft_detail_view', name='aircraftdetail'),]
```

Comment: Also, the last URL should use the proper view name of `aircraft.views.aircraft_detail_view` and not `aircraft.views.aircraftdetail`

Comment: Yes, thanks, corrected. There does seem to be a function called "aircraftdetail" but I don't understand what it is meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `aircraft_detail.html` loops over all aircrafts and displays their information. If you want to only show information for the one selected aircraft, you'll need to change the html page to something like this:

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Title: {{ aircraft.title }}</h1>
    {{ aircraft.cost }}
    {{ aircraft.range}}
    {{ aircraft.cost }}
    {{ aircraft.cruise_speed }}
{% endblock %}
```